# Do humans have a natural tendency of feeling ashamed when not wearing clothes?

Tags: anthropology

I was surprised to read on https://youtu.be/4_k5HuDTk3Q?t=2795 ([Uncontacted Tribes documentary](https://documentaryheaven.com/uncontacted-tribes/)):

[image]

The individual in the picture is part of an Amazonian tribe that was contacted a few months/years before the shooting was made

Do humans have a natural tendency of feeling ashamed when not wearing clothes?

I couldn't tell whether the statement was made as a result of his contacts with clothed people.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there studies on international differences on sexualization?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/6123/7001)

Comment: If the individual pictured and quoted is an "Amazonian tribe that was contacted a few months/years before the shooting" then it is a misrepresentation that these tribe members were uncontacted. And, surely, if they are ashamed, would they not cover up?

Comment: @ChrisRogers If you watch the documentary, you'll see that it took a few months between the first contact and this interview. No idea regarding why not wear something. Maybe too difficult to fabricate something in the jungle that is convenient to wear?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I find that difficult to believe considering I have seen documentaries showing members of different tribes (who have had influence from Western clothed people) using large leaves, gourds, animal skin etc.

Comment: @ChrisRogers fair point, not sure what's going on.